# How to compare two file to get expected result

Tags: command-line, text-processing

File A

```
Name|Dawson|Age|22|Stream|EEE
Name|Deepak|Stream|Mech
Name|Aruna|Age|20|Stream|Bio-tech
```

File B

```
Name|Age|Stream
```

Expected Output

```
Name|Age|Stream
Dawson|22|EEE
Deepak||Mech
Aruna|20|Bio-tech
```

I want to compare column 1 of file A against column 1 of file B, if matches then have to pull column 2 else should pull empty value.

Comment: Does fileB really only have one line? And should that line always be printed? And why do you say you only want column 2? Your output is showing columns 1, 2 and 3 from fileB and 2, 4 and 6 from fileA.

Comment: I would try `cat file2.txt; join -t"|" -e 'NULL' -o '1.2,1.4,1.6' file1.txt file2.txt` ... But I do think there is another idea behind and maybe you'll should use a database (SQLite?) for your data.

Comment: @dessert : I need to compare and pull data and not just combine files. Because the file might be dynamic in future so i dont need to specify the columns.
Rephrased the file A content.

Answer (score 1):

If you map each pair of pipe-separated fields as key-value into a hash (or associative array), you can then do the lookup fairly easily e.g.

```
awk -F'[|]' '
  NR==FNR {
    print; 
    n = split($0,keys); 
    next
  } 
  {
    delete a; 
    for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); 
    for(k=1;k<n;k++) printf "%s|", a[keys[k]]; 
    print a[keys[n]]
  }
' FileB FileA
```

The mapping is neater in perl

```
perl -F'[|]' -lpe '
  BEGIN{@keys = qw(Name Age Stream); print join "|", @keys} 
  (%h) = @F; $_ = join "|", map { $h{$_} } @keys
' FileA
```

(obtaining the `@keys` from `FileB` is left as an exercise).